# UIControl - changing assigned selectors: addTarget & removeTarget

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uicontrol

I'm using 10 buttons in my interface and need, from time to time, to change the button's selector.

Am I required to use:

```
-(void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

before I change the selector or can I just use:

```
-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

I'm concerned that if I change the selector using the addTarget: method sans the removeTarget: method that I'll essentially "stack up" selectors for my UIButton to fire when it is pressed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you should always remove the previously add target before assigning the new target to the button. Like this---

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 50)];

    [btn setTag:101];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];


    btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
    [btn removeTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now if you do this

```
btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then both the methods method1 and method2 will be called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that the apple docs state that passing NULL for the action: parameter "removes all action methods paired with target. 
If the removeTarget: method's receiver is a UIButton & the target is self (called in a viewController) would that remove all methods tied to that UIButton?

Since I'm only assigning one method to each button, all I need to do is pass NULL in the action: parameter ... In this case, isn't this analogous with referencing the exact method to be removed as you did in your above example?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to remove the old target/action or both the old and new actions will be performed.