# Should I removeTarget before I addTarget

Tags: objective-c, ios5

[UIControl - changing assigned selectors: addTarget & removeTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978751/uicontrol-changing-assigned-selectors-addtarget-removetarget)

States that you should remove the target before **changing** to another. However what if I am setting the target in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*? Should I remove the target before adding it again even if it is not changing? Will it call the method twice if I don't remove it or will it just overwrite it?

```
[cell.cellSwitch removeTarget:self action:@selector(notifySwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.cellSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(notifySwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my experience, it will be called only once.

But IMO, **it is better to use** `removeTarget` always because code can be changed in the future. And someday, you may need to add multiple targets and selectors.

Be a code in safe, scalable, and maintainable.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = // code with reuse identifier ...
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        // making view for cell ....
    }

    // myAction will be called ONLY ONCE after many times of scrolling
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding/removing targets, I've found that if I'm already subclassing the `UITableViewCell`, I'll add a new delegate and set the delegate to the view controller. That way, any methods called on the delegate can pass in the entire cell and therefore I can get the index path of the cell by calling `UITableView`'s `indexPathForCell` method.