# Swift UIControl target actions, how to remove for specific classes?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using such code to add target-actions to UIControl (like UIButton) as closure.

```
textField.addTarget(for: .editingChanged) { [weak self] sender in
}

func addTarget(for controlEvent: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside, target: @escaping (_ sender: Any) ->()) {
        let key = String(describing: controlEvent)
        let target = Target(target: target)
        addTarget(target, action: target.action, for: controlEvent)
        property[key] = target
    }
```

Adding event handler as closure is important as I am using this target-action inside protocol extension, so cannot define regular target action method here with @objc modifier inside this extension.

I am adding this event handler while scrolling UITableView and need to remove this target-actions when cells are disappearing from screen. 
I think I can remove just all target actions

But I rather want to be more precise and just remove Target class target-actions.

It seems that this method should work and doesn't interfere with other target-actions added in another places in code but I have some doubts

```
func removeTarget(for controlEvent: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside) {
        let key = String(describing: controlEvent)
        let target = property[key]
        print("\(key)")
        print("\(target)")
        removeTarget(target, action: target?.action, for: controlEvent)
```

I have also tried to use something like this but this doesn't work as first param should be rater target object not class type

```
textField.removeTarget(Target.self, action: nil, for: .editingChanged)
                textField.removeTarget(Target.self, action: nil, for: .editingDidEnd)
```

Any ideas? It seems that I am constantly adding new target-actions and then have several callbacks invoked also for TableView's cells that already disappeared.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978868

Comment: no i don't have reference to self 
I think this code using removeTarget(for controlEvent) works now, as I a little modified when I am updating my list of controls currently used == displayed on screen. I think this property[key] should only remove actions added as this closure for given controlEvent, so if in other parts of code I will use selector approach it will work, other solution I gave in mind is to add some id argument and then use it to save this target objects in property[key+id]